# ui component specify backend model

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

stumbled upon a problem, 
have following in my setup, but occasionally it conflicts with fileuploader so when i use ui component to add field i have no such problem.

```
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'custom_files',
        [
            ...
            'backend' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\File',
            ...
        ]
    );
```

wel since ui component is still pretty much new for me how i can specify backend model in ui component ?

```
<field name="custom_files">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            ...
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

if not mistaken source is specified as :

```
<field name="custom_files" class="Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\File">
```